# Access input value in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the value of an input inside a React form. Not sure if it is a binding issue. My console says the issue takes place in console.log(this.myInput.value.value);

```
import React from 'react';
import { getFunName } from '../helpers.js';

class StorePicker extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.goToStore = this.goToStore.bind(this);
  }

  myInput = React.createRef();
  goToStore(event){
    //Stop refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
    //Get input text
    console.log(this.myInput.value.value);
    //Change url to /store/input
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <form action="" className="store-selector" onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
          <h2>Please Enter a Store</h2>
          <input type="text" ref={this.myInput} required placeholder="Store Name" defaultValue={getFunName()} />
          <button type="submit">Visit Store</button>
        </form>
    )
  }
}

export default StorePicker;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//In constructor define like this
this.myInput = React.createRef();

//In goToStore function use this
console.log(this.myInput.current.value);
```

Comment: Thank you!! using this.myInput threw an error but using current.value fixed the issue.

Comment: No problem, happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `current` attribute of the `ref` object to get the value.

```
this.myInput.current
```

The current `attribute` of the `ref` object holds the reference of the input.

> **Accessing Refs**
>   When a ref is passed to an element in render, a reference to the node becomes accessible at the `current` attribute of the ref.

**Example:**

```js
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
  myInput = React.createRef();

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.goToStore = this.goToStore.bind(this);
  }

  goToStore(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.myInput.current.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="" className="store-selector" onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
        <h2>Please Enter a Store</h2>
        <input type="text" ref={this.myInput} required placeholder="Store Name" />
        <button type="submit">Visit Store</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<StorePicker />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
      loading.....
    </div>
```

Or you could make it controlled component and handle the value of the input with `state`.

**Working Example:**

```js
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.goToStore = this.goToStore.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      input: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  goToStore(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.input);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      input: value
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form action="" className="store-selector" onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
        <h2>Please Enter a Store</h2>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} required placeholder="Store Name" />
        <button type="submit">Visit Store</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<StorePicker />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root">
      loading.....
    </div>
```